# copying a page n number of times with pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have made a single page pdf template file.  I then use pdfbox to create a pdf with "n" number of pages (depending on report size).  I want all "n" of these pages to be the page from the template pdf file.  What is the best way to get all "n" pages to be a copy of that page?  Here is my current code:

```
PDDocument document = null;
try {
    document = PDDocument.load(WestfieldClientReportApp.class.getResource("/com/dramble/resources/template.pdf"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WestfieldClientReportView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

PDPage templatepage = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);

int n = 0;
while (n < numPages) {
    n++;
    document.importPage(templatepage);
}
```

The problem is when I have large result sets.  I'll open the pdf, it will show as 11 pages, the first 2 pages look great, but when I scroll to the 3rd page, Acrobat errors, though the template page seems to be there, but without my report data on it.  I figure the problem is probably with the code above.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it might be because when you are casting explicitely from list to PDPage, it removes its acrofields.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't appear to be saving the result. Are you?

Here is [my answer to a similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407231/can-duplicating-a-pdf-with-pdfbox-be-small-like-with-itext/19059820#19059820) which may help you.