# Use PDFBox to Merge Pages?

Tags: pdfbox

I know I can use PDFBox to merge multiple PDF's into one PDF. But is there a way to merge pages? For example, I have a header in PDF and want it to be inserted to the top of the first page of the combined PDF and push everything down. Is there a way to do it using PDFBox API?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that works to copy two files into a merged one with multiple copies of each one. It copies by pages. It's something I got using the information in the answer to this question: [Can duplicating a pdf with PDFBox be small like with iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407231/can-duplicating-a-pdf-with-pdfbox-be-small-like-with-itext)

So all you have to do is to make one copy only of the first page of doc1 and one copy only of all pages of doc2. There's a comment where you'll have to make a change to leave off some pages.

```
final int COPIES = 1; // total copies

// Same code as linked answer mostly
PDDocument samplePdf = new PDDocument();

InputStream in1 = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(DOC1_NAME);
PDDocument doc1 = PDDocument.load(in1);
List<PDPage> pages = (List<PDPage>) doc1.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

// *** Change this loop to only copy the pages you want from DOC1

for (PDPage page : pages) {
    for (int i = 0; i < COPIES; i++) { // loop for each additional copy
        samplePdf.importPage(page);
    }
}

// Same code again mostly
InputStream in2 = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(DOC2_NAME);
PDDocument doc2 = PDDocument.load(in2);
pages = (List<PDPage>) doc2.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
for (PDPage page : pages) {
    for (int i = 0; i < COPIES; i++) { // loop for each additional copy
        samplePdf.importPage(page);
    }
}

// Then write the results out
File output = new File(OUT_NAME);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output);
samplePdf.save(out);

samplePDF.close();

in1.close();
doc1.close();
in2.close();
doc2.close();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to embed a header onto an existing page. In other words, after the merge, the page break still exist. I'm looking for a way to merge/embed one pdf page before or after another without page break in between.

Comment: I don't know how to split a page and just keep the top half. I also don't know how to roll content from one page to the next while inserting content at the top of the first page. It should be possible.