# pdfbox: how to clone a page

Tags: java, pdfbox

Using Apache PDFBox, I am editing an existing document and I would like to take one page from that document and simply clone it, copying whatever elements it contains. As an additional twist, I would like to get a reference to all the `PDField`s for any form fields in this newly cloned page. Here's the code I tried so far:

```
            PDPage newPage = new PDPage(lastPage.getCOSDictionary());
            PDFCloneUtility cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(pdfDoc);
            pdfDoc.addPage(newPage);
            cloner.cloneMerge(lastPage, newPage);

            // there doesn't seem to be an API to read the fields from the page, need to filter them out from the document.
            List<PDField> newFields = readPdfFields(pdfDoc);
            Iterator<PDField> i = newFields.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                if (i.next().getWidget().getPage() != newPage)
                    i.remove();
            }
```

`readPdfFields` is a helper method I wrote to get all the fields in a document using the AcroForm.

But this code seems to lead to some kind of crash/hang state in my JVM - I haven't been able to debug exactly what's happening but I'm guessing this is not actually the right way to clone a page. What is?

Comment: I can't help you on cloning a page with PDFbox, but a page in pdf is not what you may think. The acrofields for example are not part of the page. The acrofields are in the catalog (pdf root element) and point to pages where they should appear. Cloning fields to a new page requires to either create all fields with a new name and adding them to the acrofields array with a reference to your new page, or, if the fields are to be the same fields, you need to add your new page to the page array of each field.

Comment: @thst I see. Seems I may be out of my depth a bit on this one. My knowledge of PDF is limited. Are at least those first four lines enough to get me a new page with the (non-form) elements of the old page in them?

Comment: As I said, I can't help you with using PDFBox. But stackoverflow can help: Look into this question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407231/can-duplicating-a-pdf-with-pdfbox-be-small-like-with-itext/19059820#19059820>[cloning pages]. A PDF is loaded and pages of it are imported to the same pdf. But this should work for your scenario also. Sorry for not beeing more helpful!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The least resource intensive way to clone a page is a shallow copy of the corresponding dictionary:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load( file );

List<PDPage> allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

PDPage page = allPages.get(0);
COSDictionary pageDict = page.getCOSDictionary();
COSDictionary newPageDict = new COSDictionary(pageDict);

newPageDict.removeItem(COSName.ANNOTS);

PDPage newPage = new PDPage(newPageDict);
doc.addPage(newPage);

doc.save( outfile );
```

I explicitly deleted the annotations (form fields etc) of the copy because an annotation has a reference pointing back to its page which in the copied page obviously is wrong.

Thus, if you want the annotations to come along in a clean way, you have to create shallow copies of the annotations array and all contained annotation dictionaries, too, and replace the page reference therein.

Most PDF reader would not mind, though, if the page references are incorrect. For a dirty solution, therefore, you could simply leave the annotations in the page dictionary. But who wants to be dirty... ;)

If you want to additionally change some parts of the new or the old page, you obviously also have to copy the respective PDF objects before manipulating them.

Some other remarks:

Your original page cloning to me looks weird. After all you add the identical page dictionary to the document again (duplicate entries in the page tree are ignored, I think) and then do some merge between these identical page objects.

I assume the `PDFCloneUtility` is meant for cloning between different documents, not inside the same, but merging a dictionary into itself does not need to work.

> I would like to get a reference to all the PDFields for any form fields in this newly cloned page

As the fields have the same name, they are identical!

Fields in PDF are abstract fields which can have many appearances spread over the document. The same name implies the same field.

A field appearing on some page means that there is an annotation representing that field on the page. To make things more complicated, field dictionary and annotation dictionary can be merged for fields with one appearance only.

Thus, depending on your requirements you will first have to decide whether you want to work with fields or with field annotations.

Comment: I'm still working on this issue. This answer got me started on the right path but now I have a question. Given a PDPage and its annotations, is there a way assuming a given annotation is associated with a PDField to actually get that PDField object?

Comment: Essentially you have to check whether the annotation object refers to the same PDF object (a `COSDictionary`) as the PDF object of a field or any of its kids. Having looked at the PDFBox code, though, it becomes obvious that the library assumes the fields to be in one orderly list while they actually are allowed to be organized in a tree structure with inherited attributes etc. I therefore currently (PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT) can not advice using that for arbitrary PDFs, only for PDFs you know to have their fields organized as a flat list.

Comment: Thanks. when you say "same PDF object" does that mean a `.equals()` test on the two `COSDictionary` objects would return true or is it something more subtle?

Comment: As far as I can see, `COSDictionary` and its hierarchy don't override the `Object.equals`; thus, `equals` means `==`. But I actually assume that works. If it does not, please post the pivotal code as a question in its own right.

Comment: Shouldn't it be -> newPageDict = new COSDictionary(pageDict); ?

Comment: @aleksv yes. Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: Do any of you, having worked on this, have a complete solution on transforming the COSDictionary to support the new page?

Comment: @Barry by *"complete solution"* you mean what? The above code plus annotation duplication? Or plus structure tree support for tagged documents? Or plus something else? Or plus all of the above combined?

Comment: No worries, I ended up taking a different route. The AcroForms utilize annotations for differentiating page, which means as you mentioned that one would have to replicate them to the new page and configure them. Which is the example I was seeking, of someone actually going that mile. I instead chose to use the same pdf template in a separate PDDocument instance , and merge the Documents together at the end. That way the annotations are all happy, and the "page" is the instance of PDDocument. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm also looking to clone PDF pages with the fields, I've come across:
- https://html.developreference.com/article/15446018/PDFBox+omits+form+fields+when+page+is+cloned
- https://html.developreference.com/article/12056541/PDFBox%3A+Fill+out+a+PDF+with+adding+repeatively+a+one-page+template+containing+a+form

I think that going with @Barry 's solution is easiest, though I'm curious about how you would go about actually cloning pages with their fields renamed instead of creating new documents and merging them, and which of the two solutions is more efficient.

Comment: At first glance those developreference solutions are not really complete (their way of creating field names is not collision free). And none of the solutions supports tagged documents. *By the way, you should have referenced the stack overflow questions instead of their developreference copies; on stack overflow the formatting is way better, the code is way easier to read.*

Answer (score 4):

I found out how to clone pages correctly. But links in table of contents don't work, if that's important to you.

```java
private static void createDocument(File outputFile) {
    try {
        PDDocument outputDoc = new PDDocument();
        outputDoc = new PDDocument();
        outputDoc.getDocument().setVersion(originalDocument.getDocument().getVersion());
        outputDoc.setDocumentInformation(originalDocument.getDocumentInformation());
        outputDoc.getDocumentCatalog().setViewerPreferences(originalDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getViewerPreferences());

        PDFCloneUtility cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(outputDoc);
        for (PDPage originalPage : originalDocument.getPages()) {
            COSDictionary pageDictionary = (COSDictionary) cloner.cloneForNewDocument(originalPage);
            PDPage page = new PDPage(pageDictionary);
            outputDoc.addPage(page);
        }

        outputFile.delete();
        outputDoc.save(outputFile);
        outputDoc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me; I needed to split my incoming document into multiple smaller documents, but with the same access permissions as the parent pdf. Simply importing pages into sub-pdfs means there were objects that still referenced to the main pdf. Now I know cloning is the way to go. Cheers !

Comment: Be careful, it shouldn't be used (and probably won't work later) unless you know what you're doing. See [the docs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.16/index.html?org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/PDFCloneUtility.html)