# How to clone a generated PDDocument in pdfbox 2.0.x?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using pdfbox 2.0.12 to generate reports.
I want to create 2 versions in one go, with partly similar content.
(ie: generate 1-3 pages, clone, add more pages to each version, save)

What is the correct way to copy a PDDocument to a new PDDocument?
My files are fairly simple, just text and an image per page.

The existing StackO questions[1] use code from pdfbox 1.8, or whatever doesn't work today.
The multipdf.PDCloneUtility is marked deprecated for public use and also not for use for generated PDF:s.
I could not find an example in PDFbox tree that does this.

I'm using function importPage. This almost works, except there is some mixup with fonts.
The copied pages are correct in layout (some lines and an image), but the text is just dots because it cannot find the fonts used.
The ADDED pages in the copied doc are using copies of the same fonts, the text is fine.
When looking at font resources in Adobe Reader, in the copied doc, the used fonts are listed 2 times:

> Roboto-Regular (Embedded Subset)
>
> > Type: TrueType (CID)
> >        Encoding: Identity-H
>
> Roboto-Regular
>
> > Type: TrueType (CID)
> >        Encoding: Identity-H
> >        Actual Font: Unknown

(etc)

When opening the copied doc, there's a warning
"Cannot find or create the font Roboto-Bold. Some characters may not display or print correctly"

In the source document, the fonts are listed once, exactly like the first entry above.

My code:

```
// Close content stream before copying
myContentStream.endText();
myContentStream.close();
// Copy pages
PDDocument result = new PDDocument();
result.setDocumentInformation(doc.getDocumentInformation());
int pageCount = doc.getNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
    PDPage page = doc.getPage(i);
    PDPage importedPage = result.importPage(page);
    // This is mentioned in importPage docs, bizarrely it's said to copy resources
    importedPage.setRotation(page.getRotation());
    // while this seems intuitive
    importedPage.setResources(page.getResources());
}

// Fonts are recreated for copy by reloading from file
copy_plainfont = PDType0Font.load(result, new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(plainfont_bytes));
//....etc
```

I have tried all combinations with and without importedPage.setRotation/setResources.
I've also tried using doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages() and rolling through that. Same result.

[1]
I looked at 
[pdfbox: how to clone a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084117/pdfbox-how-to-clone-a-page)
[Can duplicating a pdf with PDFBox be small like with iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407231/can-duplicating-a-pdf-with-pdfbox-be-small-like-with-itext)
and half a dozen more of varying irrelevance.

Grateful for any tips

/rasmus

Comment: I suspect the "not for use for generated PDF's" applies to ImportPage as well. This is because of ungenerated font subsets. The information would be missing in the copy.

Comment: Most likely the fool proof way to clone is to save (e.g. to a byte array output stream) and load a new document from it. In particular if subset fonts are generated, any actual cloning implementation might be to create objects for use in the same document.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies. Yes foolproof is the only thing that works for me ;)

Guess I'll go with save/reload, it's marginally easier than regenerating same pages.