# pdf file pages are inverted when sent as a multipart/form-data

Tags: spring-boot, pdfbox, rest

iam sending pdf file as multipart/form-data using rest api,
and receiving it using(@RequestParam("File") final MultipartFile multipartFile ) in the method.

the received pdf file(multipartFile) pages are inverted, but they have 0 rotation at sending end.
when i use pdfbox to get rotation of this received pdf file page it gives 180,
eventhough when i change rotation to 0 and save as new file, saved file pages are inverted(rotation=180).

```
public ResponseEntity<?> createDocument(@RequestParam("File") final MultipartFile multipartFile ){
      try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(multipartFile .getBytes());
                            PDDocument inputPDFDocument = PDDocument.load(inputStream)) {
inputPDFDocument .getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0).getRotation();// received file page rotation =180
inputPDFDocument .getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0).setRotation(0);// changed rotation to 0
    PDDocument outputPDFDocument = new PDDocument();
outputPDFDocument.addPage(pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0));// adding page to outputpdf
File outputFile=new File(path);// creating a new file
    PDDocument.save(outFile);// saving pdf to file, saved file pages are inverted.
}
}
```

case 1: Test Page : normally opened in pdf/browser
[image: test page 1]

case 1 Test Page corresponding properties
[image]

in case 1 test page has no rotation, But in properties rotate=180.
when i send this page to backend (iam using pdfbox in backend) and save the page.
saved page is 180 degree rotated(does not look correct in viewer, the viewed page is 180 degree rotated).

Case 2: Setting rotate=0 in test page properties. this causes the page to be inverted.
[image]

case 2 Test Page corresponding properties
[image]

when i save this case 2 page using backend, saved page displays no rotation(looks correct in a viewer).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Please share an example pdf showing that issue.

Comment: For most of pdf files there was no issue, the pdf file pages are intact with no rotation. But iam facing issue only with one pdf file which is 10 mb in size and it seems to be scanned very long time ago. icannot share that pdf doc.

Comment: In particular because that issue only occurs for very special files, one needs to analyze that file. If you cannot share it, please analyze its internal structure and post the peculiarities found.

Comment: One remark, though: could it be that the document has been top side down during scanning and, therefore, the pdf *looks* rotated while it simply is as scanned?

Comment: Open both files with PDFDebugger and look at what's different. Also make sure you're using the latest version of PDFBox (2.0.23). I'm wondering if the rotation might be in the parent?

Comment: Thank you mkl and tilman hausherr for your suggestions.

I analyzed the parent pdf, the page displaying in pdf reader and browser has no rotated view, but
when i see the pdf properties using ng2 pdf viewer(PDFDocumentProxy.getPage(0)._pageInfo.rotate) i saw page rotation set to 180.

 when i set this rotation to 0, pdf page is inverted. the page shown is 180 rotated
when i set rotate=90, the page shown is 270 degree rotated.

how to correct this issue at front(ng2 pdf viewer and angular 7) end or back end. on backend iam using pdfbox (ver 2.0.13).

Comment: In back end i tried to copy contents of page to new page and save doc but failed. using this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084117/pdfbox-how-to-clone-a-page/20094626 by @mkl

Comment: What I meant is the properties in the tree, e.g. /Rotate. Either share the files or post screenshots. If there is no /Rotate properly, see whether something is in the /Parent dictionary. In theory, both files should have the same entry.

Comment: *"how to correct this issue"* - what issue do you mean? It is completely OK if a pdf page with a non null page rotation setting looks correct in a viewer...

Comment: case 2 is not "inverted", it is a 180° rotation. You have to separate what you see as a human to what's in the PDF. It is quite common that pages are scanned in the "wrong" rotation, here it could be that the scanning device moves from the bottom to the top of the page. Instead of recalculating all the image bits, it's easier to set the /Rotate property. So it will look "good" for you at /Rotate 180, and no longer "good" if that is set to 0.

Comment: Indeed, what is your expectation? PDFBox does not, actually cannot know the "correct" orientation, i.e. the orientation a human viewer would consider most appropriate. It only can set the value for page rotation you tell it, and that it does. So what exactly do you hope to accomplish?